# How can I give myself mod achievements?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I recently moved my FTB Infinity world onto another machine to run it with a server.  Doing so reset my achievements.  In trying to get them back I've ran across this syntax for vanilla achievements:

```
/achievement give achievement.<achievementID>
```

It works fairly well for vanilla achievements, since the wiki has [a list of achievement IDs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Achievements#List_of_achievements), but I seem to not have such luck with the various mod wikis, as they don't seem to list the various achievement IDs.

How can I give myself the various mod-added achievements?

Answer (score 2):

Your achievements are stored in the world save, inside the `stats` folder, so they're shouldn't be lost. Each player gets a dedicated file named with their unique ID (what the Minecraft authentication server uses behind the scenes).

Check that you've properly copied your world's `stats` file into the world folder — if you just individually copied the `region` folder, `DIM*` folder, and so on into your server, you may have left your achievements behind.

Comment: Oh yes, I did notice that it used a different ID for my inventory and consequently I had to rename it.  Perhaps I have to do this for something in the stats folder as well...

Comment: @JohntheGreen Yes, the IDs should match. I'm not sure why the ID would be different locally versus on a server, but yes, the stats `.json` and player `.dat` should match their names.

Comment: Previously they always had matched the names, but since starting FTB lately it appears to have generated some kind of unique ID of the form `XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX` for my inventory.

Comment: Oh, and I've already earned certain achievements I didn't have before the move, so my question of how to grant individual mod achievements still stands.

Comment: @JohntheGreen I mean, the file names up to the dot need to match. They won't match the player name anymore, because they're using Globally Unique IDs (GUIDs) to enable the new Mojang support for name-changing without losing your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

They don't work with mods. However you can go to creative and do what they ask. If the achievement is to craft or smelt something, get it in creative and smelt it or get the materials used to make it and craft it. If it is mine something, get it in creative, throw the block or item you should mine on the floor and pick it up.

Comment: I am aware of this option, but I was hoping for something a bit quicker..